# Angular 2 http service returning immutable data issue

Tags: angular, immutable.js, angular2-http

I have a service in Angular 2 with methods like the following:

```
getEntityById = (id: number | string): Observable<Immutable.Iterable<any, any>> =>
    this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`)
        .map((response: Response) => Immutable.fromJS(this.helper.getResponseAsJson(response)))
        .share();
```

My goal is the following:

- Return an immutable version of the data from the backend so subscribers can't mutate the data in a way that affects other subscribers
- Only make fetches when the `getEntityById()` method is called directly, not when it is subscribed to, hence the use of `share()`

This *is* working correctly, but I don't like the fact that it returns an underlying type of `Immutable.Iterable<any, any>` (or `<string, any>` for that matter).

I'd like the underlying type to indicate the type of my entity, so it is more clear what is being returned to consumers of the service and that it can be enforced better.

Is there a better way to write this method so it meets the criteria I described above but also indicates the underlying type?

**UPDATE:**

So I changed this around to return the type I want, but seems pretty involved this way:

```
getEntityById = (id: number | string): Observable<MyEntity> => {
    const subscription = this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`)
        .map((response: Response) => Immutable.fromJS(this.helper.getResponseAsJson(response)))
        .share() 
        .subscribe(result => {
            this.entitySubject.next(result);

            subscription.unsubscribe();
        }, err => {
            this.logger.error(this.helper.parseError(err));

            this.entitySubject.error(err);

            subscription.unsubscribe();
        });

    return this.entitySubject.map((immutable: Immutable.Iterable<any, any>) => immutable.toJS());
}
```

I feel like there has to be a simpler way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you are doing `.map` here? I'm assuming you just have the single response?  If so, just return  `Immutable.fromJS(this.helper.getResponseAsJson(response)))`
there are also `toList()` and `toMap()` functions in Immutable you can use to convert the iterable to another type (List or Map).

Comment: Not sure I'm following you.  What do you mean by just return `Immutable.fromJS(this.helper.getResponseAsJson(response)))`?

Comment: Correct. Map is designed to iterate over a collection and map the values into something else (which is why you are getting a Iterable back). If you have an incoming array and just call .fromJS() you'll get a `List`, just like {} to `Map`

Comment: Map just projects the input to whatever you want. Doesn't have to be a collection.

Comment: Iterable is what immutable js converts the source into. Isnt related to map.